# error while attempting to deploy Dockered .net core application to Azure Container Registry

Tags: azure, docker, visual-studio, asp.net-core

Folks, this may have been asked before, i took some time trying to search for a possible root cause/solution to this but have not found anything similar enough.

Goal: I am looking to publish a Dockerized .Net Core Web App default template to an Azure Container Registry.

I have created a default application teplate for .Net Core Web App using Visual Studio 2022 targeting .Net 7.0. this is what it looked like:

[image]

i have tested running it locally on my machine which seems to be working just fine.

[image]

i then went ahead and created a publish profile targeting Azure Container Registry.

[image]

when i attempt to run the publish workflow - it seems to run into an error complaining that:

```
error from sender: context canceled
C:\FolderPath\.nuget\packages\microsoft.visualstudio.azure.containers.tools.targets\1.17.0\build\Container.targets(219,5): Error MSB4018: The "ContainerBuildAndLaunch" task failed unexpectedly.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Win32.Registry, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Microsoft.Win32.Registry, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
```

[image]

It also complains about Assembly binding logging being turned OFF. i went on to fix this issue however it had no effect on the original error about the missing file related to Microsoft.Win32.Registry.

I have tried to add Microsoft.Win32.Registry nuget package to the project explicitly. That did not solve the problem either.

I have tried to reproduce these steps on another computer workstation running different Visual Studio (Professional edition as opposed to Enterprised) and on the other computer - i am able to deploy dockerized template to Azure Container Registry just fine.

At which point i have decided i would do a full re-install of the computer system where i had a problem (it was due anyway for a while and i was putting it off). So i did a fresh Win 11 install, fresh VS install and fresh Docker Desktop install among all other things. i intentionally tried to stick to default config whenever possible.

after full reinstall - i keep hitting the same error.

i would appreciate any hint as to what might be causing the error. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try copying the `lib\net461\Microsoft.Win32.Registry.dll` file from the Microsoft.Win32.Registry NuGet to `C:\FolderPath\.nuget\packages\microsoft.visualstudio.azure.containers.tools.targets\1.17.0\tools\`.

I haven't been able to reproduce the issue. But if copying the file unblocks you, I can update the NuGet to include it going forward.

Comment: Thanks for that Nathan! really appreciate you taking time to look into this. I have now tried what you had suggested and unfortunately it made no difference. still hitting the same error. I am not surprised you are not able to reproduce this, i myself tried to do the same procedure on another station of mine and the process runs just fine with no issues. really weird.

Comment: The best way to get more information at this point is to use the tool [Fusion Log Viewer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/fuslogvw-exe-assembly-binding-log-viewer). I recommend the setting [Log in exception text](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/fuslogvw-exe-assembly-binding-log-viewer#to-log-assembly-binds-in-exceptions) which will update the exception message you've been seeing to include more information about the probing for the assembly, and why candidates like the one you copied were rejected.